# Prevent ng-click expression from firing on enter keydown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple button like this:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.method($event)">Test</button>
```

Here's what the ng-click expression looks like:

```
vm.method = function($event) {
    console.log($event.type, $event.which);
};
```

When this button has focus (by way of navigating to it via the tab key) and I press enter, I get this output to the console:

> `click 1`

To be more clear that's $event.type == 'click' and $event.which == 1.

I'm not sure why the ng-click directive allows the enter key to fire the assigned expression. Angular is recording enter keydown events as clicks. Is there a way to prevent this and have ng-click only handle click events (and ignore enter)?

This trivial bit of code is just an example, in my app I would like to use both ng-keydown and ng-click on the same component, but this particular issue is preventing me from fully implementing the functionality I want. Ideally, I'd like to have ng-keydown only handle keydown events, and ng-click only handle click events.

Comment: because that is what happens with click.... Enter triggers it.

Comment: I guess I'm confused on that point, mainly due to the fact that clicks and enter keypresses have unique event.which values: click == 1, enter == 13.

Comment: And enter can trigger click on buttons that are not in focus. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible but not best way is to check screenX/screenY/pageX/pageY/offsetX... props of $event. In case of "enter" they are equal to zero.

Comment: Ha, I never would've thought of this. I tried everything else, unsuccessfully, then tried this and it worked! Thank you.

Comment: Is this behavior for all browsers. Test for touch devices and other device browsers, you might end up disabling the whole click event if you say e.g. ...if(e.screenX ===0) { doClick();} I think you should find out why the enter press is giving wrong event of click

Answer (score 0):

Just prevent default on the key press e.g.

```
 vm.method = function($event)   {    
    if($event.keyCode === 13){ //I think
       $event.preventDefault();
    }   
    console.log($event.type, $event.which);
};
```

Comment: This might work in another case, but unfortunately the enter keypress is being logged as a click, so it has a keyCode of 1. Preventing the default behavior via preventDefault doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If your button is inside a form and it's the only button, the click event will be fired on enter when the form has focus, depending upon the browser. You should be able to check the event object in your handler method and return false if it's the enter key triggering.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-

Comment: In this case it's not a form, just an independent button.